# Why did pip upgrade from version 10 to version 18?

Tags: python, pip

while running a `pip install` script I get the following warning:

```
 You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available
```

This is very strange. Did the pip project just upgrade from version 10 to version 18? Why?

Comment: This question seems really overrated. I guess a lot of anonymous users are finding the question when they search for a similar message with different version numbers, and they don't care about the Pip version history but are simply trying to figure out how to update Pip or otherwise get rid of the message.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

First point in the release notes:

> - Switch to a Calendar based versioning scheme.
>
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/

More about calendar versioning: https://calver.org/

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! didn't even consider that calver was a thing that you'd want to have for a package manager; it seems to me to make more sense for an OS like ubuntu!

Comment: From the [pypa-dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pypa-dev/AKsd2D_F4cM), explaining not just that calver has been chosen, but the reason behind the choice: "This is the first pip release since adopting 3 month release cadence and
a Calendar based versioning scheme (also known as CalVer). In simpler
words, there will be a new pip release every 3 months unless there are
no changes since the previous release. More details such as release
months can be found in pip's development documentation."

Comment: Also from the pypa-dev mailing list it has a key highlight. - Complete PEP 518 support - includes support for installation of build. Setting the version number to 18.0 makes a nice tag to PEP 518. Otherwise, I would have expected version 11.0.