# why does the python windows installer distribute with an old version of pip?

Tags: python, windows

While various Linux distributions ship with older versions of pip, the windows installer include an ancient version 9 while current is 19.x.

Is this done intentionally?

> You should consider upgrading

Thanks, i thought i was.

Comment: Which installer are you using, exactly?  Different versions of Python are bundled with different versions of pip.  And pip v9 is not that ancient.

Comment: There is an unspoken secret about CPython: the Windows platform is the neglected child of the family, for reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not what you think, the naming convention have switched, but the version 9 is not 10 version lower than the new one.

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51476300/7348030)

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes more sense.

Very odd for a module to use dates for release naming convention but w/e.